# The Type spatial_geometry is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only primitive types can be used without qualification

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, postgresql-9.4, ef-database-first, devart

We've got an existing solution that uses EF5 and DevArt's dotConnect for PostgreSQL to connect to a PostgreSQL 9.4 database, and generate the entities.

I just installed Visual Studio 2013, and the dotConnect for PostgreSQL provider, and pulled the repository. My colleagues have the same setup, which works on their machines.

When I tried to make a build, I got the error message described in the title. I have to open the .edmx file in XML view (because VS can't show the diagram since it contains errors), and every line containing `spatial_geometry` as type has blue squiggly lines:

[image: The Type spatial_geometry is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only primitive types can be used without qualification]

When I remove the offending lines, the project builds, but then I'm missing the spatial geometry properties, which are kinda essential to the application. I can even regenerate the entities from the database, but then I get errors that the name is not valid for each of those same properties, and the properties are then simply missing.

Why does Visual Studio complain about that `spatial_geometry` type (and why does it do so on my machine but not on others')? Where does the conversion between `spatial_geomerty` and `System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry` take place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading to the newest (7.11.1190) build of dotConnect for PostgreSQL. Does this fix the issue? If you do not have access to the licensed v7.11.1190, please check the same with a trial.

Comment: The trial version of 7.11 does seem to work, thanks. I’m puzzled why the older versions work fine on my colleagues’ machines but not on mine, though.